# I want to save data entered by user to listview. i am not getting any data in my listview. highlight the issue please

Tags: java, android, listview

i am not getting any data in my listview .i am a new to this platform so you might find this easy.please update on my problem.I want to save data entered by user to listview. i am not getting any data in my listview. highlight the issue please

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
Button save, add, show;
EditText name;
Spinner city;
String personName, personCity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_save);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_add);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_show);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_city);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    show.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bt_add:
            i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.bt_save:
            personName = name.getText().toString();
            personCity = city.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (personName != null) {
                i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(personName, "name");
                i.putExtra(personCity, "city");
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Name cannot be empty", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
            break;
    }
}
}

------------------------------------------------------------------
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("personName");
    String city = intent.getStringExtra("personCity");

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(city, name, this);
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
   }}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String str_city;
String str_name;
Context context;
TextView city,name;

public MyAdapter(String city, String name, Context context) {
    this.str_city = city;
    this.str_name = name;
    this.context = context;
}
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_item, null);
    }

     city= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_city);
     name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);

    city.setText(str_city);
    name.setText(str_name);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Do as @Sushobh Nadiger answered first

Comment: my issue persists

Comment: getCount is responsible to create number of item's to be created in ListView,here your passing 0 to it.For storing city & name create Model class for it and create ArrayList<Model> to put city & name values in Model class and put it into ArrayList<Model> ,pass this ArrayList<Model> to your BaseAdapter and in getCount write return ArrayList<Model>.size() .This is how you can show all city & name data in ListView.

Comment: @Pratyush Have you used Sushobh Nadige answer?

Comment: yes i did. i m going for shrikants answer now

Comment: can you write that code for passing arraylist. i have my model class..

Comment: public class User
{
    String name, city;

    public User(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}

Comment: can you write the code for passing the ArrayList @ShrikantEkade

Comment: @Pratyush i've write code for your question ,pls find below answer & if its helps you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create model class for holding data

```
public class Model {

private String city;
private String name;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

create param constructor of BaseAdapter using ArrayList

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Model> listModel, Context context) {
this.listModel = listModel;
this.context = context;}
```

use this listModel ArrayList size to create items in ListView

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listModel.size();
}
```

Assign values to views like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

ViewHolder holder;

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.city.setText(listModel.get(position).getCity());
    holder.name.setText(listModel.get(position).getName);
    return convertView;
}
```

use ViewHolder class in BaseAdapter

```
public class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvCity;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        tvCity  =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_city);
        tvName  =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
    }
}
```

For adding more data in ListView add below function in BaseAdapter and pass it new Model object with values

```
public void addModel(Model model){
    listModel.add(model);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

//second activity code

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String city = intent.getStringExtra("city");

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setCity(city);
        model.setName(name);

        ArrayList<Model> listModel = new ArrayList<>();
        listModel.add(model);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(listModel, this);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am still getting this error..Error:(25, 21) error: constructor MyAdapter in class MyAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: ArrayList<User>,Context
found: String,String,SecondActivity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length @Shrikant Ekade

Comment: delete your BaseAdapter's constructor() ,getCount() method and use my given code

Comment: i did that already. i think now the problem is that i am passing name, city as string from my second activity to myadapter. it needs to be converted to arraylist. how can i do that?? @shrikant Ekade

Comment: In SecondActivity create Model object and put city and name data in that object and Create ArrayList<Model> object and put model object in ArrayList<Model> object and pass it to Adapter

Comment: can you write the code if possible, nothing is getting into my head right now... @shrikant ekade

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

this method is creating a problem...

don't pass 0 statically just change it to 1 or any list data you want like if you have 10 data then change dynamically it to 10. And let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 String name = intent.getStringExtra("personName");
String city = intent.getStringExtra("personCity");
```

with

```
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
String city = intent.getStringExtra("city");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.